# Model.findOne not returning docs but returning a wrapper object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nodes

I have defined a Model with mongoose like this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

var userObject = Object.create({
    alias: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    updated: { 
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

var userSchema = new Schema(userObject, {strict: false})
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

Then I created a user that I can perfectly find through mongo console like this:

```
db.users.findOne({ email: "coco@coco.com" });
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e97420d82ebdea3497afc7"),
    "password" : "caff3a46ebe640e5b4175a26f11105bf7e18be76",
    "gravatar" : "a4bfba4352aeadf620acb1468337fa49",
    "email" : "coco@coco.com",
    "alias" : "coco",
    "updated" : ISODate("2015-09-04T10:36:16.059Z"),
    "apps" : [ ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

However, when I try to access this object through a node.js with mongoose, the object a retrieve is not such doc, but a wrapper:

This piece of code...

```
// Find the user for which the login queries
  var User = require('../models/User')
  User.findOne({ email: mail }, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) throw err
      if (doc) {
        console.dir(doc)
        if(doc.password == pass) // Passwords won't match
```

Produces this output from console.dir(doc)...

```
{ '$__': 
   { strictMode: false,
     selected: undefined,
     shardval: undefined,
     saveError: undefined,
     validationError: undefined,
     adhocPaths: undefined,
     removing: undefined,
     inserting: undefined,
     version: undefined,
     getters: {},
     _id: undefined,
     populate: undefined,
     populated: undefined,
     wasPopulated: false,
     scope: undefined,
     activePaths: { paths: [Object], states: [Object], stateNames: [Object] },
     ownerDocument: undefined,
     fullPath: undefined,
     emitter: { domain: null, _events: {}, _maxListeners: 0 } },
  isNew: false,
  errors: undefined,
  _doc: 
   { __v: 0,
     apps: [],
     updated: Fri Sep 04 2015 12:36:16 GMT+0200 (CEST),
     alias: 'coco',
     email: 'coco@coco.com',
     gravatar: 'a4bfba4352aeadf620acb1468337fa49',
     password: 'caff3a46ebe640e5b4175a26f11105bf7e18be76',
     _id: { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'Uét Ø.½ê4¯Ç' } },
  '$__original_validate': { [Function] numAsyncPres: 0 },
  validate: [Function: wrappedPointCut],
  _pres: { '$__original_validate': [ [Object] ] },
  _posts: { '$__original_validate': [] } }
```

Therefore, passwords won't match because doc.password is undefined.

Why is this caused?

Comment: Use `console.log`, not `console.dir` to sanely log Mongoose model instances.

Comment: Yeah, as a fact `console.log(doc)` only printed the wrapped document, but the password validation still did not work and `doc.password` still returned `undefined` without `console.dir(doc)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's exactly the purpose of mongoose, wrapping mongo objects. It's what provides the ability to call mongoose methods on your documents. If you'd like the simple object, you can call `.toObject()` or use a [lean query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) if you don't plan on using any mongoose magic on it at all. That being said, the equality check should still hold as `doc.password` returns `doc._doc.password`.

Comment: Great. It worked! Thank you really. Do you know why in several tutorials and snippets –like [this one in mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)– the method `.toObject()` is not used?

Comment: It's not a necessity. If you're using mongoose, chances are, you want the mongoose document.

Comment: Sorry to be so insisting I want to fully understand; In the [linked example](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) mongoose object is used to access **directly** to document params (like `person.occupation`). In my case that did not work, since `doc.password` always returns `undefined` unless I apply `.toObject()` first.

Comment: Try this: `doc.password === doc._doc.password`. That should evaluate to true. In the example you linked, when you access `person.occupation` it returns `person._doc.occupation`. This is why I don't understand your error. If `doc.toObject().password` makes your code work, `doc.password` should work as well.

Comment: Thank you soo much!! This bit just helped me fix an issue that had me stuck for hours. I was trying to modify my server side rendered React app config thinking that this was a react context issue but turns out it was MongoDB.